# SendWait and foreign languages

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use `SendKeys.SendWait` with foreign characters. 
I have tried encoding (windows-1250), but it only displays the right chars with `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Could you specify the characters and the foreign language you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm using Czech. And the characters are - é, ě, ř, ť, ý, ů, ú, í, ó, á, š, ď, ž and č.

Comment: Never mind. I just need to send **;** and it will type in the right latter **ů**.

Comment: You should write an answer to your question and accept it.